# Laravel 4 multiple hasmany for same table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a laravel 4 application and in this application I need to define a model with relation to another model 2 times but with discrimination on type.

Example

```
class Car extends Eloquent{

     public function oldDrivers(){
        return $this->hasMany('Driver');
     }

     public function newDrivers(){
        return $this->hasMany('Driver');
     }

}
```

so the relation will be the `car` Id at the `driver`'s table, the thing is when I want to get the old drivers only for a certain car, it returns all drivers from both relations.

When looking into it I found because it is the same table, so now I set a type in the `Driver` model, now I want my relation to be filtered by this type, so the oldDrivers will be only drivers with the type of oldDrivers and new drivers will be the Drivers with only the newDriver type set,

How can this be done in Laravel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
class Car extends Eloquent{

     public function oldDrivers(){
        return $this->hasMany('Driver')->where('type', 'olddrivers');
     }

     public function newDrivers(){
        return $this->hasMany('Driver')->where('type', 'newdrivers');
     }

 }
```

Assumed that you have `type` field as a filter in your database. If I'm wrong about `type` field then you just change the `field` name to the right one because you got the idea that how can you add filter using a `where` clause.

Comment: How do you want to filter? using what field, for example, `->where('fieldname', 'fieldvlaue')` ?

Comment: I used it with ->where('type','oldDrivers') and it did not work

Comment: Do you have a `type` field in you `drivers` database and does that `type` field contains `oldDrivers` or `newDrivers` ? Maybe it should be `olddrivers` or `oldDriver` or even `olddriver`.